# Deploy meteor app on meteor servers thorws iron routing error

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I found some similar questions but not a clear answer about this. I have a simple meteor app. Everything works fine local but when i deploy the app on meteor servers i get an iron:router error. The strange is that when i deploy the app in --debug mode works fine.
Here is the templates

```
 <template name="navigationBar">
 </template>
 <template name="homepage">
    {{> navigationBar}}
    <div>....</div>
    {{> footer }}  
 </template>
 <template name="login">
    {{> navigationBar}}
    <div>....</div>
    {{> footer }}  
 </template>
```

And the routes are

```
Router.route('/', function () {
   this.render('homepage');
});
Router.route('/homepage');
Router.route("/login");
```

Comment: Look closely at the template code.  The `<template>` is not matched with `</template>` in the 2nd and 3rd templates.  Is it like that in the actual code?  Does fixing it help?

Comment: copy/paste error. In my html they are ok.

Comment: Is there a footer template?

Comment: Yes there is. Locally and when i deploy it in debug mode works fine.

Comment: What is the exact iron router error?

Comment: can you hit http://xpresspluss.meteor.com/?

Comment: Yes, it looks OK here.  What am I supposed to see?

Comment: I get this in the browser error console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" -- I don't think I've seen a require in Meteor code, only node.js

Comment: You don't get the iron:router splash screen?

Comment: This is probably from some bootstrap script file.

Comment: Yes I get an iron:router splash screen.  I don't see an error on it.  Is that not supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this template

```
  <template name="layout">
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

> The assistant {{>}} yield define a special dynamic area will automatically display corresponding to the path acts
>   Quote from `Discover Meteor`

And now just configure The layout Template

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'layout',
 });
```

And change the Router.rout to this.

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'homepage'});
```

It should works and its better to have the layout template, you can add stuff like "error Template" or "Waiting Template" like this, example.

```
 Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
   notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
 });
```

And the html

```
<template name="notFound">
<h1> DAMN YOU ARE ON THE WRONG PLACE GO BACK TO HOME PAGE </h1>
<a href="{{pathFor 'homepage'}}">Go main</a>
</template>
```

and loadingTemplate too, etc.

Try it it should works

Comment: Thank you......but i can't vote your answer because of my few reputations. Explain me something if you can. First of all why locally i didn't have the same problem. And second i had it like this before but instead of this Router.route('/', {name: 'homepage'}); i had this Router.route('/', function() { this.render('homepage')}); why wasn't working?

Comment: Well im pretty sure it was a version error, which Iron router version do you have? and Meteor version?

Comment: When i run meteor --version i get this Meteor 1.0.2.1  but in the versions file i have this meteor@1.1.4 and iron:router@1.0.6